# ERROR: org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle - Error during processing error message

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, wicket

I have a problem in my web application based on Apache Wicket and Spring. When I deploy the application on a Tomcat server, occasionally I have an error message like this

```
ERROR: org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle - Error during processing error message
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:662)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:104)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:104)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:133)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.getWriter(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:40)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebResponse.sendRedirect(ServletWebResponse.java:283)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.HeaderBufferingWebResponse.sendRedirect(HeaderBufferingWebResponse.java:117)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.redirectTo(WebPageRenderer.java:161)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:280)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:314)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:323)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:237)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:333)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What causes this error? It's very frustrating. I use Apache Wicket 7.5.0, Spring 4.2 and I deploy on Tomcat 7.0.7.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3997 it will help you

Comment: do not think it is this bug, rather a configuration issue, google "getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response"

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in ServletWebResponse's `#write(CharSequence)`method and see where it is being called.

Servlet specification forbids writing both text and binary in the same response. Once you use the response writer you cannot use the outputstream, and vice versa.